# Q: configuration for input-assist extension for VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I get the following 2 error messages:

1) input-assist: see the "input-assist.languages" setting

2) input-assist: input assist is not configured for any languages yet.

I can't find any documentation on how to configure the preferences file in VScode.

The files are question are .txt files. The language is english, programming language is none. Just plain unicode text files, no code whatsoever.

According to the description this extension will convert the text \lambda to the glyph λ. This is not happening.

Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

From the *author of the extension*:

Add the following code to the user preferences file:

```
"input-assist.languages": ["plaintext"]
```

The extension works well. I can now easily add logic symbols to my text files.